# mongo-express does not connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, node-modules, mongo-express

i have installed mongodb and i am able to connect via shell, now i am trying to install mongo-express, the installation was successful, i copied config.default.js file in config.js but it can't connect to mongo. As can be seen from the error it cannot retrieve the hostname

```
 (node:3085) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Could not connect to database at index "0"
(node:3085) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at /Users/name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
    at /Users/name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
    at /Users/name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/Users/name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/name/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:3085) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3085) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
Forcing the connection URL fixed it for me :

```
mongo-express --url "mongodb://localhost:27017" --admin
```

*(`--admin` option allows to list all databases)*